# Why is Vue.js not showing anything in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have installed vue.js by following these steps in Laravel 5.6 and all other dependencies are working perfectly. Only Vue.js is not responding.

```html
npm intall 
npm run dev
npm run watch
```

I am sharing all the codes on I have added. I have created a id="app" in my html file.

```html
<div id="app">
            <div class="container">
              <articles></articles>                  
            </div>
```

```html
<!-- I used this link in my html file for connecting with app.js file 
  -->
 <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

I edited the app.js file that is as under.

```js
require('./bootstrap');

    window.Vue = require('vue');


    Vue.component('articles', require('./components/Articles.vue')
    );

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });
```

I also created Articles.vue file and linked that to app.js. But my html page is showing nothing.
My file in components/Articles.Vue

```js
<template>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

</template>
```

Console is showing no errors
[image]

Vue Tab 
[image]

When I inspect DOM, I get this 
[image]

This is the Vue file. It is also not showing any tags
[image]

Comment: Are there any console errors?  Also you might need to have script tags that at least export default an empty object (i usually just stick a `name: 'SomeName'` in there)

Comment: No errors in console

Comment: Does the component show up in the vue dev tools (last tab in your screenshot)?

Comment: Yes it is the recent screenshot

Comment: Vue Dev tools has "Vue.js is detected"

Comment: I have updated the screenshot

Comment: so when you click on the Vue tab, what does it display?

Comment: where is that tab?

Comment: Its the tab on the far right of your dev tools.  Says 'Vue'

Comment: I have added more screenshots

Comment: Your inspector shows `<article>`, not `<articles>`. If it's `<article>` in your code, that's a [built-in HTML5 element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article). Try naming it something else.

Comment: Have done with compiling. I changed the name and tried but html was showing that <article> so I renamed it.

Comment: ` <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>` Not sure but this doesn't look right. `app.js` should be you vue code I assume - it's not going to be able to handle the mustache tags if it hasn't loaded. Add the relative path to your app.js file.

Comment: Vue is also not highlighting syntax

Comment: `but compiler is not showing any error. If I make any error in Vue file then it shows. I am uploading that too

Comment: @webnoob The `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>` is Laravel code. Perfectly normal - the `{{` tags there are interpreted by PHP, not Vue.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ah right, Ok thanks. Thought it worth mentioning. Too many systems using moustache syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this thread is a bit old, but as i had the same problem as you had (maybe we both watched the same youtube video "Full Stack Vue.js & Laravel"), i will still share my solution. With some research and a lot of trying around i landed on the official Laravel page (https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/what-is-mix).
The last task of this guide "npx mix" did the job for me. Everytime i change some of my js files now i use this little command to compile again and all my changes take place.

Hopefully this will help some others too :)

Answer (score 1):

As ceejayoz said in the comment: Rename it to e.g. articleElement and use it as `<article-element></article-element>`

Comment: It may be worth linking to the style guide, which has this as the first rule: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Priority-A-Rules-Essential-Error-Prevention

Comment: Itried it with different names but name in html remain same when I open console

Comment: @AliAnwar Then you're editing the wrong file, forgetting to build the JS assets (try making a change and running `npm run dev` again), or aren't sharing the actual code with us.

Comment: I did but nothing changes.